# How to insert 2 diffrent array strings in datagridview on the same row

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, datagridview

i have an win form with a richtextbox that reads from serial COM port after i give some commands like ( AT+DSCA and AT+RSSI) this 2 commands are beeing executed one after another
the strings received are as follow: 
for at+dscan  the string is like: **ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE** and i have the following vb.net code to split this string and insert it into datagridview : the first 2 values.

```
Private Sub SalveazaData()
    Dim Rows As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    For Each Row As String In Rows
        If Not (Row = "AT+DSCAN" Or Row = "OK" Or Row = "") Then
            Dim sAry As String() = Split(Row, "|")
            Dim aRow As smdDataDataSet1.smdTableRow = SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.NewsmdTableRow()
            aRow.Model = sAry(0)
            aRow.AdresaUnica = sAry(1)
            aRow.StatusModul = "ACTIVE"
            Try
                SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows.Add(sAry(1))
                SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.Rows.Add(aRow)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim u As String
                u = SmdTableTableAdapter.UpdateInactivActiv()
            End Try
        End If

    Next
```

For the second command AT+RSSI witch has the string like: **Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255** cant insert the value 255 on the same row as previous string ! i am only interested to insert on the same row as the above strings the value- "255"

Comment: does this have row have sufficient columns you need to add?  You can update the values, or add data in empty columns

Comment: yes i have suficient columns   . from the first string i only need the first 2 arays (sAry (0), AND sAry(1) and from the second string i only need 255 inserted in the same row as (sAry (0), and sAry(1)) but on different column.how to make them not interfeer.?

Comment: in which columns you want to add that values?  Are these columns names? : Model, AdresaUnica, StatusModul

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you require, To parse the values coming from COM port and use those values to be shown in datagridview.
//find out which index has this long long string value

//"ProBee-ZE Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255 Sender: 0000, "

//for example   we have sAry(3).

```
 Dim tAry As String() = Split(sAry(3), ",")
```

//You will get LQI: 255 in tAry(3), and do same process for getting 255

```
 Dim uAry As String() = Split(tAry(3), ":")
```

//you will get uAry(1) with value 255
//you need to place this code in your for loop.

```
 For Each Row As String In Rows
    If Not (Row = "AT+DSCAN" Or Row = "OK" Or Row = "") Then

        Dim sAry As String() = Split(Row, "|")
        Dim aRow As smdDataDataSet1.smdTableRow = SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.NewsmdTableRow()
        aRow.Model = sAry(0)
        aRow.AdresaUnica = sAry(1)
        aRow.StatusModul = "ACTIVE"
        aRow.thecolumnwhichuwant = uAry(1)


        Try
            SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows.Add(sAry(1))
            SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.Rows.Add(aRow)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim u As String
            u = SmdTableTableAdapter.UpdateInactivActiv()
        End Try
    End If

Next
```

Comment: This is hardcoding the value 255 in somme column ... The string i am getting has this value oscilating from 0-255 dependg on what i receive on Serial com!

Comment: You can use the variable which have this value instead of hardcoding. i have just given example.  aRow.thecolumnwhichuwant = sAry(2)

Comment: The Strings from my rtb look like this . 
ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE
ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE
ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255
for the first type of strings the code works but  for the other, i get the error " Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: from all the rows in my richtextbox i only need the values  : ZC* |0001950000008F8B and 255
the first  : ZC*=sAry(0) ,  the second: , 0001950000008F8B=sAry(1) and the third :255=sAry(3) all on the same datagridview ROW.
but when the code runs ...the value "Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI:" is consider another string and trys to update the previous value already concatenated in sary(0)

Comment: the strings from rtb are one line after another like :                            ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE              
ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE                  
ZC* |0001950000008F8B|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE              
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255                              
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255                   
Sender: 0000, Parent: FFFF, RSSI: 0, LQI: 255